# Admob ads are not showing after i published my apps on AppGallery of Huawei

Tags: java, android, admob, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Recently i created a Huawei developer account and published some apps on AppGallery of Huawei, but the admob ads aren't showing even after days from publishing the apps, i tested with admob test ad units and everything works fine but when i use my actual ad units nothing shows, i expected the ads will start showing after publishing the apps on huawei store just like on the play store but that doesn't  seem to be the case. Can any one help me with this please i tried everything but nothing works :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site is for helping others with their written code but not for problems with other sites - sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I assume there is something wrong with my code because there is some apps that shows admob ads and they aren't even published on the play store, does it have anything to do with Pro-guard ?? just pointing me in the right direction will be more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ADs Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-banner-0000001050066915)

instead of AdMob

Comment: can anyone create and Ads Kit account or its just for companies?

Comment: I am not test it yet ..But I think it is avilable to any developer